# R code to test the difference between coefficients of regressors from 2 different logit regressions

Tags: r

Let's say I have two different datasets, compiled out of the same dataset:

```
Bankrupt_Big <- filter(Bankrupt, BIG == "1")

Bankrupt_Non_Big <- filter(Bankrupt, BIG == "0")
```

So the dataset contains bankrupt companies, that are big for sample 1 and not big for sample 2. I conduct the following regressions

```
glm(DEPENDENT ~ TESTVARIABLE + controls, data = Bankrupt_Big ,family = binomial(link = 'logit'))

glm(DEPENDENT ~ TESTVARIABLE + controls, data = Bankrupt_Non_Big ,family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

let's say the variable TESTVARIABLE is significant in both samples, but I would like to know if this has a significantly larger effect in either of the groups. How should I do this, without adding interaction effects?

Comment: Sounds like you want to test for an interaction, but you don't want to estimate the interaction.  That doesn't make sense.  Can you give more explanation?

Comment: @user2554330, in my main analysis, 1 of my 2 variables that would be included in the interaction was not significant (TESTVARIABLE in the example above). I was told that therefore, I am not allowed to make an interaction TESTVARIABLE*BIG.

Comment: This sounds like a discussion that belongs in stats.stackexchange.com, not here.  R isn't going to stop you from adding the interaction.